# Detects intensity of lights using iphone camera

Tags: ios, iphone, camera

I have seen few question already asked before on same topic, but this is bit different. I want to detect intensity of light using following light's property. I already seen this [Post](http://b2cloud.com.au/tutorial/obtaining-luminosity-from-an-ios-camera) but this only fulfill my first property, or I just need to achieve this by first property.

- Illuminance (the amount of light on any given surface – measured in lux)
- Beam angle (self-explanatory)
- Colour temperature of light (measured in Kelvin)
- Lamp Source (Halogen, Metal Halide, LED etc – this one may be a step beyond technology)

Is there any possibility that I can achieve intensity of light by last three property. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post an example image so that we can see what you are trying to measure.  It's hard to know what you mean by things like beam angle without one.